# Colour gradient showing variance in line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a time-series plot of historical data which shows a single years data surrounded by shading representing the variability (up to 2 standard deviations) present in the data over multiple years. I would really like this shading to be a colour gradient, something like darker colours closer to the mean getting lighter.

So far I have managed to create a time-series graph with confidence intervals using the below code

```
> library(ggplot2)

## Here is the what the data looks like. Not lower_ci and upper_ci are just
## Mean_sales - (2 * Std_dev_sales) and Mean_sales + (2 * Std_dev_sales) respectively. 
## upper_dif and lower_dif is simply the difference between the mean and
## the confidence intervals

> head(sales_summary, 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  Date  Mean_sales Std_dev_sales lower_ci upper_ci lower_dif upper_dif
  <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 06-26   4761794.       970015. 2821763. 6701824. -1940030.  1940030.
2 06-27   4528859.       327306. 3874247. 5183471.  -654612.   654612.
3 06-28   5139476.      1105831. 2927814. 7351138. -2211662.  2211662.  

> theme_set(theme_classic())
> ggplot(data = sales_summary, 
>       aes(x = as.Date(Date, format = "%m-%d"), y = Mean_sales)) +
>  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci, 
>                  ymax=upper_ci), 
>              linetype=0, alpha=0.2,
>              fill = "blue")
```

Giving me this basic [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNRh0.png)

My current solution to create a gradient is simply to create a large number of geom_ribbons representing proportions of the variance, using the code below.

```
ggplot(data = sales_summary, 
       aes(x = as.Date(Date, format = "%m-%d"), y = Mean_sales)) +
  #geom_line(color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci, 
                  ymax=upper_ci), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.1 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.1 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.2 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.2 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.3 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.3 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.4 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.4 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.5 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.5 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.6 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.6 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,

              fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.7 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.7 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.8 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.8 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue") +

  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (0.9 * lower_dif), 
                  ymax=upper_ci - (0.9 * upper_dif)), 
              linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
              fill = "steelblue")
```

This works to give me the desired effect as can be seen in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzgd2.png) but is very copy paste heavy, especially as I have not been able to get any loops to work with ggplot (only the last iteration plot is ever returned).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `list` of geoms to a plot to add multiple geoms at once. That means you can use `purrr::map` to create the geoms with different proportions:

```
library(purrr)

ggplot(data = sales_summary, 
       aes(x = as.Date(Date, format = "%m-%d"), y = Mean_sales)) +
    map(seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1), function(prop) {
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower_ci - (prop * lower_dif), 
                        ymax=upper_ci - (prop * upper_dif)), 
                    linetype=0, alpha=0.1,
                    fill = "steelblue")
    })
```